# React:Input label up in style component

Tags: html, css, styles, react-typescript

I am using React-typescript in my app. For styling I am using [Style-components](https://styled-components.com/). I am really new Style-components. Lots of syntax are new to me. I normally use `css`. I have decided I will convert my css into Style-component. So I can use it different components. I have created one Wrapper components where I put my `Label` with style components. I also created two components one is Input and another one is Textarea. I want to use Wrapper components both Input and Textarea components. I followed one [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8YshrNwN8I). Where I converted html and css into react-css. which works fine as expected. But I am struggling to convert react css into style-components. specially the `focus` and `valid` option. I really don't know how to use them. Also I am facing difficulties when label size vary. It takes sometimes too left or sometimes too right. Here is the Image:

[image].

**I really don't know how to fix those issues.**

**This is my Youtube tutorial based on React component**

```
import React from 'react'
import './new.css'

const Test = () => {

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" className="inputField" autoComplete="off" required />
        <label htmlFor="name" className="labels">First name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Test;
```

**This is the css**

```
.main{
position: relative;
}
.inputField{
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 22px;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  font-size:18px;
  border-radius:5px;
  }
.inputField:focus{
  border: 2px solid royalblue;
  }
.labels{
  color: #8d8d8d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 55px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 300ms;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 .inputField:valid + .labels{ // I don't know how to use this `Valid` in style-component
  top: -1px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: #8d8d8d;

}

 .inputField:focus + .labels { // I don't know how to use this `focus` in style-component
  top: -1px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: royalblue;
  transition: 300ms;

}
```

**This is the wrapper component where I used Label styling with style-components and others requirements.**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`
const Label = styled.label`
  display: block;
  color: #8d8d8d;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 29px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 300ms;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
`

const Error = styled.p`
  color: red;
`

const Description = styled.p`
  color: blue;
`

export interface IInputWrapperProps {
  label?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  description?: string;
  error?: string;
  wrapperStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  children?: JSX.Element;
}

export default ({
  label, error, description, children, required, wrapperStyle
}: IInputWrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary id="InputWrapperErrorBoundary">
      <div style={wrapperStyle}>
        <Container>
          <Label>
            {label} {required && <span style={{ color: 'red' }}> *</span>}
          </Label>
          {children}
        </Container>
        {description && <Description>{description}</Description>}
        {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}
```

**This is my Input component styling with style-componenents**

```
    import React, { useState, memo } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import InputWrapper, { IInputWrapperProps } from "../wrapper";
import { Label } from "../wrapper"

const Input = styled.input.attrs(() => ({
  className: 'text-input'
}))`
border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  font-size:18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 16px 30px;
  outline: none;
  &:focus {
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
  }
  ${Label}:focus & {
    top: -12px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: royalblue;
    transition: 300ms;
  }
`



export interface ITextInputProps extends IInputWrapperProps {
  value: string | undefined;
  onChange: (i: string) => void;
}

export default memo(({
  value, onChange, ...wrapperProps
}: ITextInputProps) => {

  return (
    <InputWrapper
      {...wrapperProps}
    >
      <div>
        <Input
          value={value}
          onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </InputWrapper>
  )
});
```

**This is the parent component where I am rendering those two input fields**

```
        <InputTesting
                label="Frist Name"
                value={undefined}
                onChange={(i) => console.log(i)}
              />
              <br></br>
              <br></br>
              <InputTesting
                label="Hello"
                value={undefined}
                onChange={(i) => console.log(i)}
              />
```

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer the question, I need to say two things: first, I couldn't understand so much about your styled-components code, so I'll just transform your react/CSS code to react-typescript/styled-component. Second, I didn't get what you mean by "difficulties when label size varies", so I'm not focusing on this in the answer. That been said, let's go to the code.

### Input.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface InputProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>{
    id: string;
    label: string;
}

const InputGroup = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;

const InputLabel = styled.label`
  color: #8d8d8d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 55px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 300ms;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
`;

const InputField = styled.input`
  outline: none;
  padding: 16px 22px;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  &:focus
  {
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
  }

  &:valid + ${InputLabel}
  {
    top: -1px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #8d8d8d;
  }

  &:focus + ${InputLabel}
  {
    top: -1px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: royalblue;
    transition: 300ms;
  }
`;

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ id, label, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <InputGroup>
      <InputField id={id} {...rest} />
      <InputLabel htmlFor={id} >{label}</InputLabel>
    </InputGroup>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

The idea here is to create an input component that already has a label inside it. Initially, I create an interface called *InputProps* which extends all attributes from a common InputElement and forces the parent component to put an *id* and a *label* attribute.

Them I used styled-components to copy all styles from the youtube guy. To put pseudo-classes on styled-components you have to use a sass' feature called [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector). Using the ampersand, you can refer to the parent selector. Another thing you have to use is [styled-components reference](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs). This feature will allow you to refer to the styled-label in the code.

Now that you've created the Input component, let's use it on the App.

### App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import Input from './Input';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Input required type="text" label="First Name" id="first-name" />
      <Input required type="text" label="Hello" id="hello" />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[This is the final result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh6ND.png)